# Why is my JSON data with null not returning 0 causing an exception?

Tags: python, json

I have an API which returns null when there are no results, else it's usually got a count with an int.  In this minimal example with a similar data structure, if either value is null I'd hope to return 0.

I thought that adding `{}` usually allows traversing deeper into the data I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/Documents/projects/data-reviews/test_code.py", line 52, in
>
> total_reviews = data.get('data', {}).get('node', {}).get('reviews', {}).get('aggregates', {}).get('count', {})
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

I'm not what to do here or it try: except: the only option?

```
import json

resp = """{
    "data": {
        "node": {
            "myReviews": {
                "totalReviews": 0
            },
            "allReviews": {
                "aggregates": null
            }
        }
    }
}"""

data = json.loads(resp)

total_ratings = data.get('data', {}).get('node', {}).get('myReviews', {}).get('totalReviews', 0)
total_reviews = data.get('data', {}).get('node', {}).get('allReviews', {}).get('aggregates', {}).get('count', 0)
```

Comment: The default value is only used by `get` if the key does not exist at all. If the key exists and the value is `None`/`null`, you’ll get `None`.

Comment: Is the only option to wrap in a try except then?

Comment: If your structure is always the same, why do you need the default values for the `get`?

Comment: Sometimes aggregates contains null, other times an object {'count': 30}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fallback argument of the `get` method only gets used if the value is not defined. If `get` explicitly returns `None` then that is the result.

Like you write, the common workaround is to use `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    total_ratings = data['data']['node']['myReviews']['totalReviews']
except KeyError:
    total_ratings = 0
try:
    total_reviews = data['data']['node']['allReviews']['aggregates']['count']
except KeyError:
    total_reviews = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've done.  I can't believe this is the first time it's ever happened to me!  Will mark it correct unless someone else comes up with a more elegant solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional `object_hook` function to replace the `null` value.

```
import json


def as_null(resp):
    if "aggregates" in resp and resp["aggregates"] is None:
        print(resp)
        resp["aggregates"] = {'count': 0}
        print(resp)
    return resp


resp = """{
    "data": {
        "node": {
            "myReviews": {
                "totalReviews": 0
                
                
            },
            "allReviews": {
                "aggregates": null
            }
        }
    }
}"""

data = json.loads(resp, object_hook=as_null)
total_ratings = data.get('data', {}).get('node', {}).get('myReviews', {}).get('aggregates', {}).get('count', 0)
total_reviews = data.get('data', {}).get('node', {}).get('allReviews', {}).get('aggregates', {}).get('count', 0)
print(data)
print(total_ratings, total_ratings)

----------------------

{'aggregates': None}
{'aggregates': {'count': 0}}
{'data': {'node': {'myReviews': {'totalReviews': 0}, 'allReviews': {'aggregates': {'count': 0}}}}}
0 0
```

Or use it to immediately get the `count` values you need.